# retrieving a url path in a jsf/primefaces backing bean

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Assuming a URL pattern like

```
http://company.com/jsf-app-root/{groupName}/show.xhtml
```

and the actual URL

```
http://company.com/jsf-app-root/accountant/show.xhtml
```

How do I get the value `accountant` in the backing bean?
I would be fine with either as managed parameter to the constructor or as member of the bean.

The only thing I found were query parameter solutions query parameter solutions: [a](http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.de/p/view-parameters-in-jsf-20.html), [b](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsf22-1377252.html)

Or some manual work

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestPathInfo();
```

Is there really no support for url path parameter in jsf/primeface?

Answer (score 0):

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath();
```

Check JavaDocs: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestContextPath()

Comment: so it remains maunal work, if the context path contains more than one level. ugly. Thanks so far